# Develop Android App from iOS Code

Tags: android, ios, xcode, port

I'm supposed to port an iOS app to Android. I have the iOS project in front of me but i do not have XCode to open it.
So I have some questions:

1. Is there a way to open the project on Windows? I DON'T need to build it or anything, I just want to see the correct file structure (because the file structure isn't the same in the project and on the hard disk).
2. How do you recommend to handle updates? The iOS app will always be updated first and my job is to update the Android app afterwards, according to the new iOS code. Is there a good software where I can see all the changes made to the iOS project? Or is this a stupid idea?
3. If you happen to know any good resources for android developers to understand the basics of iOS apps (not Objective C, more the structural aspects), let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. In what format do you have it? You can use textedit or nano or vim or anything to open the individial .h and .m files.
2. Yes, have you heard of github? You can check the revisions. Additionally, if you know the high level feature overview of what you will be developing sometimes you may not need to see the other platforms code at all...
3. https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/cocoa-touch.html + google

Comment: Yes I can open all the .h and .m files, the problem is that all these many files are all in the same folder (together with all the fonts and images and everything). If you opened the project in XCode, the files would be well structured and I could structure the android app the same way.